# Is it possible to block the S Pen Air Command menu from opening with the pen button press in my application in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, motionevent

I'm developing an Android application in Kotlin, and I'm encountering an issue related to the S Pen functionality on Samsung devices. Specifically, I want to prevent the Air Command menu from opening when the user presses the button on the S Pen.

I've searched extensively but haven't found a clear solution. Is there a way, either through Android Studio or via code, to intercept or block the default behavior of the S Pen button press that opens the Air Command menu while the user is using the app?

Any insights, suggestions, or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to override the onTouchEvent method to ignore touch events specifically triggered by the stylus button press, but it didn't work:

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
// Ignore the click event from the stylus button or if the user is not using the pen
if (event.buttonState and MotionEvent.BUTTON_STYLUS_PRIMARY != 0 ) {
    // Return true to indicate that the event has been handled
    return true
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Samsung proprietary S Pen API?https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-spen-remote/air-actions.html

Comment: Hey, thanks! I encountered some issues while trying to define the <remote-actions>. Did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used this SDK.